# How instagram storing hash tag and locations in story

Tags: android, instagram, hashtag

How instagram storing hashtag in stories and retrieving into same place?
is that a image or a layout (the hashtag content) above the image ,
if its a layout how the layout is showing in correct place with dimension 
  [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUrDn.jpg)